# Cocoa/Swift: NSStatusBarItem's text gets trimmed when using a picture

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

When creating an NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar related application for MacOS, I stumbled upon a problem that seemed strange to begin with. The problem is: when using an image and a text for the NSStatusBar, the text was being clipped unless you manually specified a sufficient length, which would be hardcoded and causes problems with alternating lengths. How can this be solved?

```
// The -1 is supposed to mean "variable length"
let myStatusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(-1))
myStatusItem.image = NSImage(named: "customImage")
myStatusItem.title = "Some special information"
```

This would be the normal case where this problem will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with some ridiculous variations, I realized that the problem can be fixed when using **BOTH** *.title* and .*attributedTitle* parameters of the NSStatusBar item.

Also make sure that you declare the .image **BEFORE** you declare the titles. If you want to use the *.attributedTitle*, define it after *.title* - if you want to use the plain *.title*, just define it after the *.attributedTitle*.

```
// The -1 is supposed to mean "variable length"
let myStatusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(-1))
myStatusItem.image = NSImage(named: "customImage")
myStatusItem.title = "Some special information"
myStatusItem.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Some special information")
```